# Using an present-participle verb as conjunction?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, coordinating-conjunctions

Seeking feedback on the validity of this sentence, which tries to use the present-participle "helping" as a kind of conjunction:

> (company name) is the best marketing platform helping teams think big
> and grow fast

It doesn't pass my smell test. I'd love to know:

- Is it valid? (with or without punctuation like a comma before
  "helping" to separate clauses)
- If not, what rules does it break.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Smell is an aesthetic sense, and there is an aesthetic objection, which I share.  It doesn't smell good to me either.  But there is  pandemic of promotional straplines:  VEGBOX REFRESHING YOUR DINNER TABLE; XBANK KEEPING YOUR MONEY SAFE. Your sentence is, by contrast, at least a sentence.  Some would say a comma after "platform" would help. But why do think that participle is acting as a conjunction?

Comment: *Helping* is a verb there, not a conjunction. Same with *is* and *think* and *grow*.

Comment: You have a **reduced relative (adjective) clause** here. *Company X is the best marketing platform that is helping teams think big and grow fast.* --> *Company X is the best marketing platform **helping teams think big and grow fast**.* Compare: *Karen is the only lady who is wearing a red dress.* --> *Karen is the only lady **wearing a red dress**.*

Comment: There's no such thing as a 'reduced' relative clause. Syntactically the bracketed clause in "Company xyz is the best marketing platform [helping teams think big and grow fast}" is ambiguous. One possibility is that it's a gerund-participial clause modifying "best marketing platform", the other that's it's an adjunct in clause structure.

Comment: @BillJ: Of course there is such thing as a reduced relative clause, just not in the CGEL grammar framework to which you subscribe. There are other grammars.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Gerund-participial and past participial clauses as modifiers in NP structure can't be some form of relative clause, since there is no possibility of them containing a relative phrase, a crucial and distinguishing feature of relative clauses. And of course there's no antecedent, another feature of relatives. Moreover, relatives are for the most part finite, whereas the others are non-finite.